# Get Database Table in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to get Database tables as per  ObjectType , how can i achieve this?
so far i tried this method

```
 public void  GetTableByObjectType(string ObjectType) {
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
          "Data Source=Local;Initial Catalog=myConnection;User ID=sa;Password=12345");
          DataTable t = conn.GetSchema("Objectype");
```

Comment: You're looking to get just the list of tables in your database?

Comment: I believe that GetSchema will get You the schema of DB -> all tables, all views, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you get all the tables from the database that you're trying to access

```
string SQLExpression = "SELECT * FROM SYS.Tables Order By Name";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
              "Data Source=Local;Initial Catalog=myConnection;User ID=sa;Password=12345");

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLExpression, cn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

adp.Fill(ds, "SystemData");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example you get the schema of the tables of your db:

```
String ObjectType = "Tables"; //collectionName argument to get Tables

String[] tableRestrictions = new String[4];
tableRestrictions[2] = "TableYouWant"; //name of the table whose get the schema
DataTable courseTableSchemaTable = conn.GetSchema(ObjectType, tableRestrictions);
```

You can use four restrictions for Table collection, so you should create a 4 members array.
For the array `tableRestrictions`:

- *0-member represents Catalog;*
- *1-member represents Schema;*
- *2-member represents Table Name;*
- *3-member represents Table Type.*

see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms136366(v=vs.110).aspx